# Dynamics CRM IDs tables purpose

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I investigated dynamics crm database and find a lot of tables that contains only Ids such as RoleBaseIds,EntityIds, OptionSetIds, RelationshipIds;
i want to know the purpose of these identity tables as the database already include tables for Roles, entity, optionset and relationship; also, is this design affect performance as it will include a lot of joins to obtain data

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to investigate the Dynamics CRM database, the only things you can consider are the Filtered Views.

This link is related to CRM 4.0 but the concept is still valid:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc308184.aspx